# Graph that average degree node is 4 in R

Tags: r, graph, igraph

How can i create a random graph that average node degree is 4?

After creating a random graph ,how can i find how many links are in the graph?

I found a function for K-Nearest Neighbor Graph , is there any function for average node degree?

```
    library (igraph)
    g4 <- random.graph.game(100, p=5/100)
    graph.knn(g4)
    degree.distribution(g4)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for that function, R is pretty good at calculating averages:

```
mean(degree(g4))
# [1] 4.58
```

The number of edges is reported by `ecount`:

```
ecount(g4)
# [1] 229
```

To generate a random graph that has average degree 4, you can use G(n,m) graphs. If these satisfy your needs, you can generate them using `random.graph.game`:

```
g5 <- random.graph.game(10, 10 * 4 / 2, type="gnm")
mean(degree(g5))
# [1] 4
```